# How to test simple if condition containing method call in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to jasmine I need to write jasmine unit test case for below code .

```js
if(checkForRelationship()){
  var relationship = localStorage.getItem('relationship');
}
else{
  localStorage.setItem('relationship',{id:'someId'});
}

   // where  checkForRelationship method is like below

function checkForRelationship(){
  
  return !!localStorage.getItem('relationship');
  
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different scenarios so you need to test each one:

```
describe("Relationship in local storage", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(localStorage, "getItem");
    spyOn(localStorage, "setItem");
  });

  it("should set relationship in localStorage if it doesn't exist", function() {
    localStorage.getItem.and.returnValue = null;

    run() // <- Here you put whatever you need to make your code run

    expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith("relationship", { id: "someId" });
  });

  it("should not set relationship in localStorage if it already exists", function() {
    localStorage.getItem.and.returnValue = "truthy";

    run() // <- Here you put whatever you need to make your code run

    expect(localStorage.setItem).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

That should get you started at least.
It would be nice to test that `localStorage.getItem` is called too but since you always call that as part of your check, which is an implementation detail, that test isn't very meaningful.

I would also suggest that you abstract away `localStorage` with a module of your own so that you don't create spies directly on the native `localStorage`.